# What are the similarities between scripting language and programming language?

Tags: scripting, programming-languages, similarity, difference, scripting-language

By searching I have found a similarity that is both import libraries. But unable to point out any other similarities, as everywhere I can see only differences.

Comment: What sources are you using? Scripting languages are a subset of programming languages - some programming languages are scripting languages, and some usually aren't considered to be scripting languages. Also, is there a particular distinction you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Scripting languages ***are*** programming languages. Most of the programming languages in use today that once deserved the *"scripting"* label are complete programming environments from the syntactically, semantically, and library-wise.

At some point *"scripting language"* may have been used for languages that were suitable only for writing short *scripts*, but today any language that doesn't require a complex compilation step to run and that provides a [read–eval–print loop (REPL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) is considered good enough for scripting.